# “Page” not visible in “New” menu

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

**The problem**

I, and at least one other user (both owners), don't see “Page” in the “New” menu of a page that has been made the homepage of a site.

[image: No “Page” in the “New” menu]

As you can see, other elements are missing.

**Informations that may be of help**

If I click on the cogwheel next to my face, I can create a page from there (but it doesn't offer me to choose a page layout like it usually does).

[image: “Add a page” in the cogwheel menu next to my face]

Also if I go on another page (the original homepage), there “Page” appears in the “New” menu. Actually, it's the only element that appears. And there it offers me to choose a page layout.

[image: Only “Page” in the “New” menu]

I can also create a page from the pages library. And there it doesn't offer me to choose a page layout.

[image: “Site Page” in the pages library]

There's a third-party application on that site, it's ArcGIS. There's a classic page containing an ArcGIS map.

If I go in advanced permissions and I check my access to the site, it says that page creation is denied (see “What I've tried so far”). And actually it's the same for any user I tried.

**What I've tried so far**

I have the same message as the person who published this post [there](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/add-and-customise-pages-permission-denied-yet-i-am-site-admin/m-p/1453537). The best answer gives two solutions:

1. Allow custom scripting from the SharePoint admin centre

These parameters were already set to “Allow”.

2. Use the following PowerShell command.

I did, more than 24 hours ago, and everything is the same as before.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70349569/unable-to-add-new-page-in-sharepoint-online-pages-library) it suggests :

“1.Go to library settings -> Check whether it has Page content type. If it does not have, please add the Page content type.”

It has the Page content type.

[image: “Page” is in the content types]

**Request for help**

Is someone able to help me?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the issue on my end. Not sure what caused this, you can create a service request with Microsoft in M365 admin center and experts from MS will help you figure out this. The alternative to this issue I would suggest is to create a new page and migrate the issued page to the new page and set the new page as home page.
By the way, as per my knowledge create site page in the pages library doesn't allow you to select layout. This is by design.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Right now, the person I'm helping is satisfied with the workaround “Create a page from the cogwheel next to face”, but I'll be sure to apply the “Set a new page as homepage” method if he'd like to have a homepage with a complete “New” menu.